# Must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package

Tags: postgresql

I feel stupid: this afternoon I noticed I have too many `PostgreSQL` installed so I uninstalled all of them using `apt-get purge remove`. Then I try to install only the latest `PostgreSQL` version 11, but I had problem get the client running.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and here are the commands I have used:

1.Install `postgresql`

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-11
```

2.Install `postgresql-client`, also version 11

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-11
```

But when I run `psql` I still got an error, saying this client is not installed.

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA$ psql
Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
```

Any idea? I found this question under which [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301997/error-you-must-install-at-least-one-postgresql-client-version-package) says that modifying the PATH variable might help. But it seems the PATH for `psql` is correct because I do not get a "command not found error". Also that OP did not seem to have installed a client, but I have.

What went wrong in my case?

Thanks!

**Edit** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301997/error-you-must-install-at-least-one-postgresql-client-version-package), as I explained in the last paragraph. 1) In that question, the user did not install `Postgresql-client`, but I did, and it still did not solve my problem. 2) Also, part of that question is about setting the correct `PATH`, which I probably did because my error did not seem to be related to `PATH`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301997/error-you-must-install-at-least-one-postgresql-client-version-package)

Comment: @YavuzSelim thanks for sharing the link. I actually read this question and its answers, and explained why this is not a duplicate in the original post. Edited with a more explicit explanation above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
begin by restarting postgresql server and see if that helps.

Run "netstat -tnlp" you should see a row that contains ":5432" like this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

If you you don't see 5432, but instead 5433 or 5434 it means postgres is not running on the default port. In that case edit

```
/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
```

and change "port = 5434" or whatever it is to "port = 5432", then restart postgresql server.

If that doesn't work, try downgrading to postgresql 10 and see if that works

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I eventually removed everything and reinstalled postgresql from this guide and it worked. Not sure what broke in my previous installation though. https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-postgresql-11-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-servers/